# In JSONPath, how to find keys matching a 'non existing' filter?

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

Here is a json snippet containing a definition structure :

```json
{
  "Type": "page",
  "Label": "Test",
  "Children": {
    "crud": {
      "Type": "crud",
      "Datasource": "crud_data",
      "Children": {
        "level1": {},
        "group": {
          "Type": "group",
          "level2": {},
          "Children": {
            "level3a": {},
            "level3b": {},
            "level3c": {}
          }
        }
      }                        
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to find a JSON expression to find every key under "Children", which do not contain any "Type" property inside.

How to say "no Type property" inside an object ?

In the example, I'm expecting this result:

```json
[
  "level1",
  "level3a",
  "level3b",
  "level3c"
]
```

Note the "crud" and "group" are excluded because they define a "Type" property. Other objects are empty in the example, but could contain properties other the Type and should still match.

I imagine a solution like this : `$..Children.*[?(a filter here saying no Type)]~`

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

For most implementations, `@.Type` on its own should be an existence check and can be negated with `!`.  So this should get you most of the way there:

```
$..[?(!@.Type)]
```

The problem that this presents is that this returns *every* child value that doesn't have a `Type` property, regardless of what kind of value that is.  For example, `"page"` doesn't have a `Type` property because it's not an object; it doesn't have *any* properties.  But you only want objects.

But JSON Path doesn't have a way to isolate a particular kind of value.

If you were to take the result of this path and then filter for objects, you should get what you want.